# convert access group by query to sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, group-by, sum

I'm unable to convert MS Access query to SQL SERVER Query, with changing the group by columns because it will effect in the final result. The purpose of this query is to calculate the Creditor and debtor of accounts of projects.

I tried rewriting with 'CTE' but couldn't get any good result.. I hope someone could help me.. Thanks in advance...

this is the query I want to convert:

```
SELECT Sum(ZABC.M) AS M, Sum(ZABC.D) AS D, ZABC.ACC_NUMBER, ZABC.PROJECT_NUMBER, [M]-[D] AS RM, [D]- 
[M] AS RD
FROM ZABC
GROUP BY ZABC.ACC_NUMBER, ZABC.PROJECT_NUMBER
ORDER BY ZABC.PROJECT_NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the query are `[M]` and `[D]` in the `select` clause: these columns should either be repeated in the `group by` clause, or surrounded by an aggregate function. Your current `group by` clause gives you one row per `(acc_number, project_number)` tuple: you need to choose which computation you want for `D` and `M`, that may have several different values per group.

You did not explain the purpose of the original query. Maybe you meant:

```
SELECT 
    Sum(ZABC.M) AS M, 
    Sum(ZABC.D) AS D, 
    ZABC.ACC_NUMBER, 
    ZABC.PROJECT_NUMBER, 
    Sum(ZABC.M) - SUM(ZABC.D) AS RM, 
    SUM(ZABC.D) - SUM(ZABC.M) AS RD
FROM ZABC
GROUP BY ZABC.ACC_NUMBER, ZABC.PROJECT_NUMBER
ORDER BY ZABC.PROJECT_NUMBER;
```

There is a vast variety of aggregate functions available for you to pick from, such as `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, and so on.

Comment: Can we do it without using Sum function in the last two lines

Comment: @xamo; see my edited answer for more details about the problem. Which value do you want in these columns?

Comment: I saw edits sir, the purpose of this query is to calculate the Creditor and debtor of accounts of projects.

Comment: @xamo: ok. Doesn't the query I suggested gives you what you the result you want?

Comment: It's almost give the result, but i must check the accounts with accountants first, is there any other way we can rewrite this query...

Comment: @xamo: I have no idea what you mean. I explained the logic on how to make this query valid standard SQL - you need to pick the relevant aggregate function fo these columns.

Comment: Thank you very much, the query you  suggested gives me the result I want